# React router v4 authentication issue

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-router-v4

I am trying to make basic authentication flow in my react app.

I'm using redux and redux-persist to store my state into localstorage.

Here is a `PrivateRoute` component to check user auth then redirect to Login or the actual component (which is private).

Its working fine when `authenticated` set to false. But when i log in successfuly it does not render my component even my `authenticated` was true. *(I logged variables and I saw authenticated is true, login success)*

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isAuth } from 'redux/actions/auth/A_auth';
import App from 'layout/pages/App';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      const {authenticated, component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
      console.log(this.props);
      return (
         <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            authenticated ? (
               <App>
                  <Component {...props}/>
               </App>
            ) : (
               <Redirect to={{
                  pathname: '/login',
                  state: { from: props.location }
               }}/>
            )
         )}/>
      );
   }
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
   authenticated: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      authenticated: state.auth.authenticated
   }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

When `authenticated == false` it redirects to `Login.js` but when its `true`it does not render actual component. When i removed if statement and just render `<App><Component.../></App` it is working fine, but authentication is not working in this case.

Here is my index.js which is root render.

```
render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router children={routes}/>
</Provider>, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

And here is my routes.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from 'layout/pages/home';
import NewClient from 'layout/pages/newclient';
import EditClient from 'layout/pages/editclient';
import Login from 'layout/pages/login';
import PrivateRoute from 'routes/PrivateRoute';

export default (
   <div>
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} exact/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} exact/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/client/new" component={NewClient}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/client/edit/:apiKey" component={EditClient}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
   </div>
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I changed this

`<Redirect to={{
 pathname: '/login',
 state: { from: props.location }
 }}/>`

to this

`<Login/>`

Redirect component causes problems still don't know why.